# Perforce visual client (P4v) shortcut icon not displaying

Tags: icons, perforce, shortcut, p4v

I run the Perforce Windows client, P4V, on both my office computer and my laptop. On the office computer it displays a standard P4V icon (a silver 'V' in a red circle). On the laptop it displays a generic icon that looks like three colored blobs in a window.

On the laptop I tried to change the icon in the P4V shortcut's Properties dialog. When I clicked "Change Icon" I got an error box that said, "Windows can't find the file %USERPROFILE%\Documents\...\p4v_IDI_ICON1.ico." The pathname refers to a folder that I created to store notes. There's no reason why a Perforce icon *should* be in that folder. I'm mystified that Perforce is even aware of the folder, since it's not in any depot.

I looked for the named .ico file in my office computer's Perforce installation directory. It's not there.

What can I do to make the Perforce icon display correctly on the laptop?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select the icon from the executable, which is likely at `"C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4v.exe"` (or `%PROGRAMFILES%\Perforce\p4v.exe` in the generic).

On my system the icon was assigned by the installer, and has a cryptic path into the Windows Installer folders, but, I am also able to use the icon from the exe above.

Answer (score 0):

The P4V executable file on the laptop does not contain any icons at all -- that's the cause of the problem.

I did figure out a way to solve the problem, though:

1. On the office computer, open the P4V shortcut's Properties dialog.
   Click Change Icon. The Change Icon lists one icon (the one I want).
   "Look for icons in this file" gives the pathname of a weirdly named
   EXE file in a directory named %systemroot%\Installer.
2. Email the weirdly named EXE file to myself as an attachment.
3. On the laptop, save the EXE file.
4. Open the P4V shortcut's Properties dialog. Click Change Icon. Enter
   the pathname of the saved EXE file in "Look for icons in this file." The
   dialog shows the icon I want.
5. Select the icon and close the dialog.

Now the right icon appears in the task bar when I start P4V. The wrong icon still appears in the Start menu, but I hope that that will correct itself the next time I reboot.